# SQL Server Foreign Key Problem With Tables

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

Today I come with a quick question. I'm creating a DB for a shoe store, after inserting a few rows into my first table, I went on to add a few others to my second table (I only have 2 tables). And upon running the code, I get this error:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'ForeignKey'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Product'. The duplicate key value is (reebok).

I'm not sure what is going on as the "categoryid" is the same in both tables. But here is the first code I executed then the second that gave me the error message

Table 1:

```
INSERT INTO [myStore].[dbo].[category] ([categoryid], [description])
VALUES ('puma', 'men'), ('nike', 'women'), ('reebok', 'children')
```

Table 2 (caused the error message)

```
INSERT INTO [myStore].[dbo].[product] ([productid], [description], [categoryid], [price], [size])
VALUES (1, 'Running Shoes', 'puma', 70, 'L'), 
       (2, 'Slides', 'nike', 45, 'S'),
       (3, 'Kids Soccer Shoes', 'reebok', 55, 'M'),
       (4, 'Kids Football Shoes', 'reebok', 40, 'L'),
       (5, 'Basketball Shoes', 'nike', 90, 'S')
```

Comment: Your `INSERT` includes categoryid `adidas`, which is not in the `category` table.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you for that friend I had not realized my error there. However, it does bring me another error even after changing it.

Comment: I got another suggestion for you.  Why are you not using number as [Category_id] ref as fk. Going to be faster. unless your db is going to be really small. With minimal DML ops.

Comment: @junketsu I might as well if I can't figure this out. And yes it would be a very small database as this is just to test for future creations. Also this might have to do with some constraints and foreign key adjustments i have made prior to creating the table so i will have to see.

Comment: I see from the new error that you have a unique constraint on categogy, which will allow only one category for a given product. That unique constraint looks to be a mistake and should be dropped.

Comment: That unique constraint is certainly POORLY NAMED!

Comment: Keep in mind FK in 1 table is PK in another. So PK in [category] table = 'reebok' and you already inserted that once into [product] cant insert it again.

Comment: @DanGuzman That must be my mistake. I will try and go back and fix it, thank you for your input.

Comment: and while your at it consider the case of sub-categories as well. Any of those makers have shoes, clothes, accessories. So your better option is to create a composite primary key based on Category + Sub-category... or in this case you can even get away with identity(1,1) as your PK on [Category] table.

Comment: @junketsu a yes that is very smart. I will add that. Just going to start my DB from scratch to completely overhaul it.

Comment: then make sure in your insert statements to still not add idenity column as that is self populating. so your insert statement will be something like insert into table [Category] values ('adidas', 'men', 'shoes'), ('nike',''women', 'headband') ,etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'ForeignKey'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Product'. The duplicate key value is (reebok).
```

Your keyword is - unique key. Adding these two will pop this error:

```
(3, 'Kids Soccer Shoes', 'reebok', 55, 'M'),
(4, 'Kids Football Shoes', 'reebok', 40, 'L'),
```

Check your indexes on your "ForeignKey" where it seems as this column is set to unique value in whole table.